# I need to convert string(for example A5) into one string (A) and one int (5)

Tags: c++

I need to convert string(for example A5) into one string (A) and one int (5) .

I don't have any ideas to solve this problem.
Want do do:

```
int convert(string y)
{
 ???
 return poziom , pion; //(A=0 in pion, 5=5 in poziom) 
}

{
 int poziom; 
 int pion;  

 string x;
 cin >> x; //A5  

convert(x);
cout << pion << poziom; // pion=0 , poziom=5
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return poziom , pion;` does?

Comment: `int convert(string y) {}` can only return 1 integer since you declared it to return an `int`

Comment: I'm writing a game. Gamer have to give to program coordinate in board like chess.

Comment: You can do `char pion; int poziom; cin >> pion >> poziom;`. Then you don't need to convert.

Comment: If you want to return two values, you can return a single `struct` a `std::pair`, a `std::tuple`, etc.  consisting of two values.

Comment: I am already use: cin >> pion (string) and cin >> poziom (int) but it is 
uncomfortable for user.

Comment: The user can input the same string "A5". If `pion` is a char then only the first character will be read from the input and written to the variable.

Comment: @Fresh2054 -- Then make the input comfortable to the user, and then your code has to parse the input.

Comment: "I am already use: cin >> pion (string) and cin >> poziom (int)"  ... thats not the same as the suggested `cin >> pion >> poziom;` (pion has to be a `char` for this to work as expected)

Comment: btw read about the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) to understand why seeing `return poziom , pion;` should make you shiver

Comment: If you want it to be convenient for the user, define a type that represents your coordinates, then overload `>>` and `<<`. Include validation of the input so the user doesn't need to do it.

Comment: a bit more into the direction of trying to rescue this question: You should rather post a mcve of your code, explain what it does and what it should do instead. This would make a much better question compared to "I want this. Gimme the codez" (though there still might be plenty of duplicates / other questions that cover the same)

Comment: char pion; int poziom;
  cin >> pion >> poziom;
  cout << pion << poziom;  This solved my problem thanks. I was tring to convert it but this is more simpler. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solutions to your problem. First of all this is a XY problem. You can separate the input:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int poziom;     
    char pion;
    std::cin >> pion >> pozium; //"A5"  

    std::cout << pion << poziom; // pion='A' , poziom=5
}
```

If you want you can read the input as string and split it

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::pair<char, int> convert(string s) {
    return std::make_pair(s[0], s[1] - '0');
}

int main() {
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x; //"A5"
    auto [pion, poziom] = convert(x);
    std::cout << pion << poziom; // pion='A' , poziom=5
}
```

The conversion from char to int with

```
s[1] - '0'
```

works because it's guaranteed that all digits are consecutive and ordered, even if not ASCII is used. That means that

```
'1' == '0' + 1
```

and so on for all character encodings used with C and C++.